# python alternative solution for split function

Tags: python, python-3.x, input

```
while bulls != 4:
    userinput = list(map(int,input().split()))
    for i in range(len(userinput)):
        if userinput[i] == Guess[i]:
            bulls += 1
```

So code is working for example when guess (it's a list) [1,2,3,4] and user input is 1 2 3 4.
Code is working only when user gives input with space (because of map(.split())) can you show me how can it work with an input without space character?

Comment: You only expect single digit integers? `12 34 56 78` would be invalid input…?

Comment: it would be enough if you explain to me how it works with single digit integers.Thank you for that already.

Comment: You don’t really need to split anything. A string is an *iterable* of individual characters. Meaning, `for c in input()` loops over the individual characters in the string. The same way, `map(int, input())` converts every individual character into an int…

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because a string is an iterable, you can iterate over its characters.

If you want to split the user input after every digit, this can be done easily:

```py
userinput = [int(c) for c in input()]
```

or to keep your original approach:

```py
userinput = list(map(int, input()))
```

Both attempts result in userinput being the list of integers `[1, 2, 3, 4, 5]` if user entered `12345`.

Answer (score 0):

If you want it to work with or without spaces:

```
[int(c) for c in input() if c != ' ']
```

or:

```
list(map(int, filter(lambda c: c != ' ', input())))
```

You can iterate directly over the string, as that will yield each character individually. A string is an *iterable* of individual characters.

FWIW, you could write your code pretty succinctly like so:

```
for i, n in enumerate(int(c) for c in input() if c != ' '):
    if n == guess[i]:
        bulls += 1
```

See [`enumerate`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#enumerate).

Or something like:

```
userinput = (int(c) for c in input() if c != ' ')
bulls += sum(n == g for n, g in zip(userinput, guess))
```